# What could cause something like that ? PHP - MYSQL failure

Tags: php, mysql

Firstly i want to explain how my script works..

I'am using script named TSUE and source code protect by ioncube. Script has own plugins system kind of like vbulletin's Addons system. For using this system i need to create new php function to get data from database and i need to create a template for use(show) them as i want.

I created very simple plugin sample code. I'm getting tid and added coloum in tsue_torrents table with this function;

and using by this template i can show this data which page i want!

here is template

(template name is example btw. need to call that template using by eval in function)

```
<div class="widget">
<h4>Plugins Example</h4>
<br />
{$output}
</div>
```

Everything is look fine

But when i add this plugins on my main page or anypage of script I getting error like this;

```
��\IsG�>��%x!��n�(.���d)D�94��]J��]�$A����4a}�.sҍ��z_VU/ @��/��@-�YYY�U�w��|������~�ܦ�Lz���ѷk����SK�z��н�   �ч�v)7�q�m"���u�c&O:�$B�����Nm���œ �m6OOO<!І�/rP�V�5��f�� �s%�@;�� �4MT*S_t���=�����n������˷��7��D�Lw���4S�l�w�%@u��� Ⱥ/����p?�S�s�]�?o �c_�=�~*�u4�]��/*�'B-<[�<�T�ϓ�J'S`�>w�*?s���/�1K�ߩ�9j$:_��F<���O:��g~G79��~t���1��8�|��$��b?��H�T����L:)pq�C���P�4����Ӑ�+G|(zC�C�&�8�:�����9je)!����$�1�)�g1��p�B���̐g!-��N���D*' �Q*�o5�NJ<'%Ha��v,#A_$<���φ2��F�z.O�0J$��&.k,����6]�M�'9��&B@��*�4���Yʾ�Q�i� ���A�P��yV�n��ݴ��tJ?�&8�mO�h�3�ד(Jk�h��iVY��8v��Ô��k��Gˌ����B���b�5�"}��g��c>��vU�}���.l�:h��� `k��4KB=Ȃo�K 0QCz@#=;���k�& 7m�+�Q4n�"m�I��E��x�>>�zNO���Ta�M䉆�H�}��v9k�Ӫ���a+�+��#��R����=h7-�H�����R�S�3�a���O�zݨʜ�Ԩu�Ғ��ԮL�mI>i��#�n��f��Juj�=_��0<��zyj�U�9�Z�k�y��H��J�0>����'8L�Z?K�(��QF�B7�������E�uB:�$�i����m�hV�F��AHU�փ� �,�!��wjZ�U��6�pH8y��@OOe� c��5C��\�ɼ    :�.���Q]$�lm����%��I�=� ���C��Р��@O�89Pk5����M����f�]_�cc
```

Screenshot : [image]

Comment: if `ioncube` is encoding your php, is there a decoder also installed?

Comment: my file not encoded. External plugins are not need to encoded. I'm using a few external plugins which they are not encoded , and they are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay; I found why i get that weird error.

I think it is because Dreamweaver CS6.. I don't know excatly reason but when i type my code another php editor , function work fine..

Comment: What charset do you save your files with?